# How to provide the Gekko Python with the first and second derivatives of the objective function?

Tags: optimization, least-squares, derivative, gekko

I am trying to minimize the difference of a function with a data point over different time points. So the objective function is the sum of the squares of the difference between the model (my function) and the data points over different times.

My model has analytical first and second order derivatives. How can I provide these derivatives to [Gekko Python](https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)?

Comment: As @Junho Park correctly mentioned, Gekko provides the 1st and 2nd derivatives. While this could be left up to the user, it would take quite a bit of work for the gradients to be provided in the exact sparse form needed by each solver. You may want to try another solver that allows you to provide your derivatives if you want to use those in the optimization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several examples in the APMonitor webpage regarding parameter estimation. Please check the link below. It also provides the data and model that you can use for practice.

[TCLab C - Parameter Estimation](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/TCLabC)

You can also get the idea how to implement the higher order differential equations in GEKKO in the link below. You basically want to introduce additional variable which links the first derivative variable to the 2nd derivative variable. That way, you can collapse the higer order DE down into the multiple 1st order DEs.

[Solve 2nd Order Differential Equation](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Apps/2ndOrderDifferential)

Comment: I am a bit at lost! I want to provide the gekko solver with my own analytical first and second derivative of the objective function.
Could you please give an example code? How do I give the first derivative of the objective function in this example: https://gekko.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quick_start.html#example

Comment: Gekko computes the 1st and 2nd derivatives using the automatic differentiation method in the backend. It provides the information for the built-in gradient-based solvers such as IPOPT.